# Which is correct? "Date" vs. "date on" in a question

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrases

> Can you tell me what date you wrote this article on?

or

> Can you tell me what date you wrote this article?

Which is correct? Or are both correct?

Edit: I would assume the first variant is grammatical because the answer would contain the preposition "on". E.g. "I wrote the article on Oct 12th, 2012." But maybe the preposition is unnecessary in a question.

Comment: What do you already know about the acceptability of each sentence? Providing that information will help you to get better answers (and possibly prevent this question from being closed).

Comment: I couldn't honestly tell you. I would assume the "on" variant is correct because the answer would contain the preposition "on". E.g. "I wrote the article on Oct 12th, 2012." Perhaps the preposition is unnecessary in a question. I don't know which is more idiomatic; I'm not a native speaker nor a linguist.

Comment: Got it. Answerers often like to see that askers have made some effort to research the issue before asking, so I recommend including that information in your question. (Comments might be deleted at any time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that the second sentence is **strictly** grammatical, but it is acceptable in spoken or informal written American English. An article is finished **on** a date.

> You wrote this article what date

is simply not grammatical. But actual, informal usage, at least in the U.S., is not so strict with regard to prepositions that link items in different clauses. In formal writing, however, I’d not use the structure in the second sentence.

You did not mention a third possibility.

> Can you tell me on what date you wrote this article

is not more correct grammatically than your first sentence, but many may find this third option better stylistically because the usual wording is “**on** a date” and therefore keeping the two words close together makes the sentence slightly easier to parse.

Comment: You can't say "You wrote this article what date." But you can say "You wrote this article July 5th." I suspect that that is the source of the confusion.

Comment: @alphabet Good point. The use of ellipsis in English must drive non-native speaker mad.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and both mean exactly the same thing. However they ask **can** to which the answer is either "yes" or "no" since can means "are you able to". Presumably what you really want is the actual date so the question should be "What date did you write this article on?"

Comment: Or "On what date did you write this article?"